# The interpretation of comparatives

Tags: sentence-construction

Imagine in a pie chart, A and B take up 34% and 25% of the total respectively.

Can I say 'A is ahead of B by 9%'? Or can I say 'A is 9% more than B'?

Is there a possibility that the above sentences would be interpreted as A equals 25%*(1+9%), which is 27.25%?

Comment: A is 9 **percentage points** greater than B **(not 9 percent)**. "Ahead" doesn't make any sense, and I have never heard of it used like that for percentages and charts. A is **36%** more/higher/greater than B.

Comment: A pie chart is not a competition. You cannot say "A is ahead of B" in this context unless you were intentionally being humorous.